# My app fails on OS X 10.6: "Failed to load Machine.config"

Tags: macos, mono, monodevelop, xamarin.mac

I've finally finished my Mac app after 7 months of work. However, on most people's Macs the app won't run at all. In console.app they get the error message "Failed to load Machine.config". Why?

The app is built with MonoDevelop and PackagerMaker, and has been signed correctly.

Comment: Please provide all the version information (MonoDevelop about dialog will give you everything) in your question. Also details how you're build (e.g. build log) your application - things can gets very different based on your project's settings.

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.5, Monodevelop 3.1.1, Mono 2.10.9, Xamarin.Mac: 1.0.11, XCode 4.5.2, PackageMaker 3.0.5, All the latest dev stuff as far as I can tell. This is my app http://www.hippostudios.co.uk/Download.aspx?Name=Downloads/HippoAnimator2.zip

Comment: Xamarin are working on a hotfix for me so hopefully that will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Xamarin.Mac 1.0.19